# Why does my animation not work

Tags: jquery, html, css

For some reason this animation isn't working. I want it to look like http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/TypographyEffects/index6.html I don't understand why it is not working the same. On an unrelated note, I also put a background color of black, because my background image isn't quite working sometimes. I am not sure why. Thank you!
The code is

```
body {
background-image: url('http://images.fanpop.com/images/image_uploads/SNL-Wallpaper-saturday-night-live-784022_1024_768.jpg');
background-size: cover;
background: #000;
}

.letter-container h2 a{
text-align: justify;
float: right;
margin-right: 100px;
font-size: 130px;
line-height: 160px;
display: block;
padding-bottom: 30px;
color: #fff;
cursor:default;
text-decoration: none;
}
.letter-container h2 a span {
color: #000;
opacity: 1;
text-decoration: none;
-webkit-transition: all 0.3s linear;
-moz-transition: all 0.3s linear;
-o-transition: all 0.3s linear;
-ms-transition: all 0.3s linear;
transition: all 0.3s linear;
-webkit-animation: sharpen 0.9s linear backwards;   
-moz-animation: sharpen 0.9s linear backwards;  
-ms-animation: sharpen 0.9s linear backwards;
animation: sharpen 0.9s linear backwards;
}
.letter-container h2 a span:nth-child(1) {
    animation-delay: 0s;
}
.letter-container h2 a span:nth-child(2) {
    animation-delay: 0.1s;
}
```

I only put a few :nth childs, because I didn't want to fill up the post.

```
@keyframes sharpen {
 0% {
 opacity: 0;
 text-shadow: 0px 0px 100px #fff;
 color: transparent;
 }
 90% {
 opacity: 0.9;
 text-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #fff;
 color: transparent;
 }
 100% {
 color: #fff;
 opacity: 1;
 text-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #fff, 1px 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
 }
}
```

(I also have the keyframes for each of the web versions)
The html and Javascript is

```
<div id="letter-container" class="letter-container">
    <h2><a href="#">Saturday <br/> Night <br/> Live</a></h2>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(function() {
                    $("#letter-container h2 a").lettering();
                });
            </script>
```

Edit: To look at it on a website it is http://spencedesign.netau.net/SNL/SNL.html I don't understand how this doesn't do anything. And yes I did add in the jquery lettering

Comment: What's your lettering() function? Did you forget to include the library?

Comment: [The working page](http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/TypographyEffects/index6.html) includes the [`lettering.js` plugin](http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/TypographyEffects/js/jquery.lettering.js) and your jsFiddle does not.  Also, if you want to run jQuery in a jsFiddle, you can't select Mootools... select "jQuery".

Comment: Adding to Sparky's comment, once you choose jQuery 1.8 (or whatever version you want) in the dropdown menu, you can just put straight jQuery into the jQuery module...no need for the script tags!

Comment: lettering.js is found the typography page and fiddle doesn't contains the lettering.js and also please select jquery instead of mootools

Answer (score 0):

This at least fades in like you're wanting (but not character-by-character). For that, I would check the CSS, because it looks like it's doing it for each nth-child of the h2 letters. Make sure you have a delay set for each character in "Saturday Night Live", including the spaces.

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/JonMoore/b6Wfg/1/)

```
.letter-container h2 a span:nth-child(1) {
    animation-delay: 0s;
}
.letter-container h2 a span:nth-child(2) {
    animation-delay: 0.1s;
}
.letter-container h2 a span:nth-child(3) {
    animation-delay: 0.2s;
}
.letter-container h2 a span:nth-child(4) {
    animation-delay: 0.3s;
}
.letter-container h2 a span:nth-child(5) {
    animation-delay: 0.4s;
}
[...etc]
```

Comment: Wouldn't the nth child be for every character?

Comment: I don't understand how it works(to a degree) in that jsfiddle, but not on my website http://spencedesign.netau.net/SNL/SNL.html#

Comment: Try using this as your source instead of "jquerylettering.js" ---> http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/TypographyEffects/js/jquery.lettering.js

Answer (score 0):

sorry this may be slightly off topic but how come google comes up with nothing on reference to:
**animation: sharpen** 0.9s linear backwards;
???

i would like to learn more about this and i cant find it documented anywhere, nor if there is the reverse operation ie. blur which also interests me..

trust me i wouldnt be here asking if google gave me something but sadly to no avail, anyone know?